# Text offsets canvas and affects mouse-hover location

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a header as shown in https://codepen.io/nikspatel/pen/aJGqpv. However, if I add some text inside the header like:

```
<div id="large-header" class="large-header">
    <h1 style="font-size:150%;">Dummy Text</h1>
    <p style="font-size:100%;">Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text Dummy Text</p>
    <canvas id="demo-canvas" width="1280" height="840"></canvas>
</div>
```

Then the particle-effect's mouse-hover gets offset by the text.

What should I do so that the hover effect remains at the center of my cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gautamnaik1994/pen/NZevwx?editors=0110)

Make your canvas position absolute.

Add this to your css

```
.large-header {
  background: #f58;
  position: relative;
}

.large-header canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;/*to be able to select the text*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the set the position on the canvas.

```css
.large-header canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
```